# What is the fastest webserver solution with the lowest memory footprint?

Tags: webserver

I need a webserver to serve up very simple POST/GET requests as JSON.  I don't need MVC, Rails, Django.   I need something that takes up very little memory, preferrably around 5K per reqeust. The webserver will talk to backend services like Scribe using Facebook Thrift.  Each http request will also access a SQLLite database, one for each user and user's data do not overlap.  It will serve up static html files as well as the json webservice.

I am considering the following:

- Njinx with PHP,
- Kepler from Lua,
- rolling my own with libevent or libev perhaps calling out to Lua, or
- MochiWeb.

Which of these options are best and what other options are out there?  I can use PHP, python, or Lua for basic scripting and even could do basic C.  I am leaning towards some sort of Erlang solution.

Answer (score 41):

I've had a good experience with nginx (https://nginx.org/), that said, when choosing a webserver, you should look closely at your requirements and make an informed decision as these things can be very application specific.

You'll notice that in this question that a lot of people recommend g-wan, Webmachine, etc... these are all things you should look at and benchmark to see if they are faster for your use case.

This is the kind of question that encourages cheerleading, there is no "right answer".

Comment: Seconded. Nginx is very fast, especially for serving static content.

Comment: Nginx is slower and uses more CPU and memory resources than others, like Lighty or G-WAN, see http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=/discussion/525/webserver-scalability-varnish-nginx-lighttpd-g-wan-rpscpuram so stacking +1 votes is mere cheerleading rather than technical information.

Comment: I have tried one of them, G-WAN is unstable.

Comment: @Gil oh my god man thank you ! it's so liberating to come across g-wan.

Comment: @Gil, Who told you man "nginx is slower, uses more CPU and memory"? I am sorry to say you are far from the truth. I have practically used IIS, Apache, MiniHttpd and Nginx. I have found Nginx is the fastest one.

Answer (score 11):

As one of the authors of Webmachine, I'm happy to help you out.  One reason I'm following up is that even though there's no JSON-related code in Webmachine, you might find it useful to know that we use it on a daily basis for processing many different JSON requests and responses.  It's simple, cleanly extensible, and performs reasonably well.

If you just wanted static delivery, then something like nginx or lighttpd would be an obvious way to go.  For a mix of static and dynamic requests and built-in good Web behavior, you may find Webmachine a good fit.

Check out the trivial example code at http://code.google.com/p/webmachine/wiki/ExampleResources and the recent posts on the blog at http://blog.therestfulway.com/
for more information.

It has worked out well for us; if you have questions feel free to drop me a line.

Answer (score 9):

Cherokee webserver at www.cherokee-project.com

Comment: In my tests, the Cherokee reverse-proxy module was much faster than the one in Nginx.

Answer (score 9):

To measure the footprint, have a look at the executable size (don't forget shared libraries).

TrustLeap G-WAN (150 KB, no dependencies) offers Java, C/C++, Objective-C and D scripts.

According to these benchmarks, it also uses less memory and CPU resources than Nginx or Lighttpd while running faster:

http://www.gwan.ch/benchmark

Comment: Compared to the others solutions proposed above, G-WAN is not OpenSource (is Freeware software that is NOT Free Software). It only implements HTTP 1.0 (and some stuff from HTTP 1.1 like Keep-Alive), does not support E-Tag header (but If-Modified-Since). The benchmarks in his homepage are amazing but the best way to see if it works for you or not, is testing your application with it and compare it with the other solutions.

Comment: @krenel00: open-source was *not* a requirement of the question and G-WAN implements HTTP 1.1 including E-Tag *since years*. Why do you feel necessary to spread false information?

Comment: @Gil, I'm sorry about the E-Tag. http://gwan.ch/en_timeline.html it says that in 7-jul-2009 they added support to E-Tag. I readed somewhere that was not supported; the information about G-WAN is very sparse on the Internet. When I choose a product it's very important for me to know if I will rely on the developer of the tool or on a Comunity. The developer of a private software can decide to discontinue the project, and that's something to take into account when you decide the technology you choose. Is not a requirement of the question, just a bad side of you anwser.

Comment: It is remarkable to see how far away from the question you believe that you must go to find arguments against G-WAN. Instead of relying on the reliable source (G-WAN's site), you refer to (unidentified) third-parties which sould not be so "difficult to cite" since you also state that *"information about G-WAN is very sparse on the Internet"*. This Q&A platform is not aimed at spreading F.U.D. so please try to keep the record straight: **G-WAN is doing in 3 years much better than the incumbents in the past 20 years**.

Comment: http://www.shisoft.org/index.php/2016/06/06/crashing-the-g-wan-web-server-at-the-speed-of-light/

Answer (score 8):

[Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) has an excellent footprint, to the extent that most of your memory will probably taken up by whatever language you choose to use (unless you go the C route, which is really not recommended).

Comment: It does. Nginx handles requests much faster though. Similar memory usage, though.

Answer (score 7):

There's an article on IBM developerWorks with a pretty extensive list of "lightweight" web servers:
[Lightweight Web servers: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ltwebserv/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130914054933/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ltwebserv/)

Answer (score 7):

Mochiweb is super lightweight, and handles a stupidly high load.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest embedded web-server hands down is Snorkel - checkout there web site, they destroyed nginx in my testing using ab.  http://sites.google.com/site/snorkelembedded

Answer (score 4):

G-WAN (150 KB including ANSI C scripts) has a native JSON parser, probably the fastest available given the features (it lets you search entries by name or by value in addition to import/export from/to text).

Beating the 150 KB footprint (server + script engine included) will be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-1). I think that's exactly what the information you are looking for. You don't need a full featured web server, so using Erlang+libevent/libev should be good.

Answer (score 3):

For C or Lua, Mongoose is an option, https://github.com/valenok/mongoose .
It uses more than 5k per request, mostly because the per-connection data has a buffer for the request + headers preallocated, and maximum request size is set to 16k by default. This is tunable though, there is no problem to make it less than 5k, just change `#define MAX_REQUEST_SIZE 16384` in mongoose.c when you embed Mongoose. In terms of footprint, it is around 50k compiled on disk not counting Lua (in case you need it) and SSL (also, in case you need it). Runtime footprint depends on OS.

Comment: +1 I wrapped this with a C++11 REST server http://github.com/nurettin/pwned

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned Python, you might want to take a look at [web.py](http://webpy.org/), for a very simple way to listen on port 80 and map URLs to actions.

It'll also run via your favorite CGI if you want to pair with a standard webserver (i.e. behind Nginx/FastCGI) -- and I'll second the recs of Nginx for massive concurrency on static files. (They used it with Lighttpd at Reddit.)

[thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/) is the other webserver I'd look at, especially if memory is extremely scarce, like on an embedded system.

Comment: +1 for web.py. It's stupidly well done for lightweight POST/GET/PUT/DELETE apps and an overall makes it easy to organize a RESTful architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at klone at koanlogic.com site ... being targeted at embedded systems it's very small, and incidentally very fast too: http://john.freml.in/teepeedee2-vs-klone .
It can be scripted in C/C++ (ultra performant) or usual PHP/CGI (a lot less performant), depending on skills/taste ...

Answer (score 1):

If could code in C or C++, I think lighttz would be the fastest and uses the least memory. However, the reason why it is so is because it's using libev and it has absolutely nothing, no php support, no html support - nothing. All it provides is a call back function where u handle each http request. You're are gonna have to parse the http GET/POST request and return the html as a string. You can see it being benchmarked against nginx, lighttpd, apache etc and come up on top ([link](http://www.zenebo.com/word/asynchronous-programming/lighttz-a-simple-and-fast-web-server/)).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at FAPWS (Fast Asynchronous Python WSGI server). The philosophy of the project match perfectly your needs. 
http://www.fapws.org

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is compared to Varnish (the cache used by Facebook) and Apache Traffic Server (the cache used by Yahoo!):

And, Igor Sysoev, the guy behind Nginx, has not been short of [comments on his blog](http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/serving-small-static-files-which-server-to-use/#comment-120).